# I can not change pages and static blocks from magento backend. blank page

Tags: magento

I experienced an issue on my website in Backend  magento.  I can not display pages and cms blocks ( gives me a blank page ) . Frontend to the site is fully functional. I tried to disable the modules but nothing . The problem is only on the pages and on the blocks to frontend I state that I was made a server migration . What causes the problem ? Thank you

Comment: Blank page usually means unreported fatal errors. Try [enabling error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/3219919) to see what the exact error is.

Comment: Is your home page visible? and only clicking to anything giving you 404?

Comment: My page in frontend is visible. Backend only pages and static block give me a blank page. The other things, in backend, works fine. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: as suggested by zoli , did you enabled error reports : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display/21429652#21429652 ?

Answer (score 0):

sometime it possible that the page and static block empty but in that case we change anything from theme menu in the mage

Comment: I dont' t understand.  In my log there is an error in config.php. But i don't understand what is the problem

Comment: i didn't understand that i suggest u about how to work when u have no code in your page and static block

Comment: u have to use filezilla to access that page and run on your localhost

Comment: I tried to see mistake by excetion.log but does not give me anything. In the system log me from this
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: MSP_Common in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 851
ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach () in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 870

I do not know if this may be the problem. How would I go to get back to the code ?. I tried editing the php.ini but not right.

Comment: Mage::log(print_r($xmlString, true)); 
Mage::log(print_r($this->_elementClass, true));

Comment: @Mav first of all I am unable to understand anything as your English is awful, second I feel that you must re-check your server configuration as you said that you recently migrated to new server.

Comment: @vishwa rata sorry for my English. I try to re-check my server configuration. Thanks